# Maximum in the sum of elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I think that next property is true, but I can´t find where it is proved:

"Given $x_1,\dots,x_n, y_1,\dots,y_n \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $$\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\{x_i+y_i\} \leq \max_{1\leq i \leq n}\{x_i\}+\max_{1\leq i \leq n}\{y_i\}$$

Maybe is simply applying Minkowski's law?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x_{i_0}+y_{i_0} = \max_i(x_i+y_i)$. Then
$$
\max_i(x_i+y_i) = x_{i_0}+y_{i_0}\,\le\,\max_ix_i + \max_iy_i.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

$x_i \le \max_{1\le i \le n} (x_i)$; $i=1,2,..,n$.

$y_i \le \max_{1\le i \le n}(y_i)$, $i=1,2,..,n$.

$x_i+y_i  \le $

$\max_{1 \le i \le n} (x_i) +\max_{1 \le i \le n}(y_i )$, $i=1,2,..,n.$

Finally:

$\max_{1 \le i \le n} (x_i+y_i) \le$

$ \max_{1 \le i  \le n}(x_I)+\max_{1 \le i \le n}(y_i )$.